# Deploy a laravel project on firebase

Tags: laravel, firebase

I have a laravel project which uses sqlite. I want to publish this application to firebase but i dont want to use the database of firebase. Because my tables have been populated already and relationship between them. I know how to publish a static content website on there, but i couldn't find any source about this.

I mean, of course there are a lot of tutorial, article about how to deploy laravel on firebase via using Kreait. But as i mention, i dont want to use firebase realtiem database.

Actually i dont have any idea its possible or not with sqlite. Is it possible to publish a laravel application on firebase hosting with sqlite? Or is it a must?

Im just new to firebase. So i may be missing something on to understand the concept of it.

Comment: If you're looking for a free host. Look into heroku

Answer (score 2):

**Firebase hosting is a host for static websites**

Firebase hosting does not support any server side scripts such as **Ruby, PHP, Python or anything else that is processing your files before output**. That would require a application engine such as Google App Engine, Heroku, or similar. The hosting service is a static website hosting service.